# equivalent to evrnd(mu,sigma,m,n) in Python

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, random, distribution

I want an alternative to this **Matlab function** in **Python**

**`evrnd(mu,sigma,m,n)`**

I think We can use something  like this

`numpy.random.gumbel`

or just

`numpy.random.uniform`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: see this: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.genextreme.html#scipy.stats.genextreme

Comment: Thanks I will look into it.

Comment: Are you needing a Gumbel or a more general Extreme Value distribution?  If a Gumbel, the inverse CDF is easily accessible, but depends on if that works for you. Note a uniform distribution is not a substitute for either of these.

Comment: Related:  [How to Generate Samples from the Gumbel Distribution using the Inverse Transform](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/374932/177387).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matlab's [`evrnd`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/evrnd.html) generates random variates from the Gumbel distribution, also known as the Type I extreme value distribution.  As explained in that link,

> The version used here is suitable for modeling minima; the mirror image of this distribution can be used to model maxima by negating R.

You can use [NumPy's implementation of the Gumbel distribution](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.Generator.gumbel.html), but it uses the version of the distribution that models maxima, so you'll have to flip the values around the location (i.e. mu) parameter.

Here's a script containing the Python function `evrnd`. The plot that it generates is below.

```py
import numpy as np


def evrnd(mu, sigma, size=None, rng=None):
    """
    Generate random variates from the Gumbel distribution.

    This function draws from the same distribution as the Matlab function

        evrnd(mu, sigma, n)

    `size` may be a tuple, e.g.

    >>> evrnd(mu=3.5, sigma=0.2, size=(2, 5))
    array([[3.1851337 , 3.68844487, 3.0418185 , 3.49705362, 3.57224276],
           [3.32677795, 3.45116032, 3.22391284, 3.25287589, 3.32041355]])

    """
    if rng is None:
        rng = np.random.default_rng()
    x = mu - rng.gumbel(loc=0, scale=sigma, size=size)
    return x


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    mu = 10
    sigma = 2.5
    n = 20000

    x = evrnd(mu, sigma, n)

    # Plot the normalized histogram of the sample.
    plt.hist(x, bins=100, density=True, alpha=0.7)
    plt.grid(alpha=0.25)
    plt.show()
```

[image: plot]

---

If you are already using SciPy, an alternative is to use the `rvs` method of [`scipy.stats.gumbel_l`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gumbel_l.html).  The SciPy distribution `scipy.stats.gumbel_l` implements the Gumbel distribution for minima,
so there is no need to flip the results returned by the `rvs` method.
For example,

```py
from scipy.stats import gumbel_l                                      


mu = 10
sigma = 2.5
n = 20000

x = gumbel_l.rvs(loc=mu, scale=sigma, size=n)
```